# Finding overall time

Tags: python, python-3.3

Trying to find the total time worked in this. Cant seem to figure out what I have wrong.

```
#Problem 3, Python, Extra Credit
hourStart = int(input("Please enter the hour that Jimmy started work."))

minStart = int(input("Please enter the minute on the hour that Jimmy started work."))

hourEnd = int(input("Please enter the hour that Jimmy ended work."))

minEnd = int(input("Please enter the minute on the hour that Jimmy ended work."))

lunchHourStart = int(input("Please enter that hour that Jimmy started lunch."))

lunchMinStart = int(input("Please enter the minute on the hour that Jimmy started lunch."))

lunchHourEnd = int(input("Please enter the hour that Jimmy ended his lunch break."))

lunchMinEnd =int(input("Please enter the minute on the hour that Jimmy ended his lunch break."))

start = hourStart * 60 + minStart

end = hourEnd * 60 + minEnd

totalTime = end + start

lunchStart = lunchHourStart * 60 + lunchMinStart

lunchEnd = lunchHourEnd * 60 + lunchMinEnd

lunchTime = lunchEnd - lunchStart

timeWorked = (totalTime - lunchTime) * 60

hoursWorked = int(timeWorked)

min = (timeWorked - hoursWorked) * 60

print (min)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `totalTime` be calculated as `totalTime = end - start` (subtraction, not addition)?

Comment: yeah, think that was wrong but I am still getting 0 as an answer

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and, importantly, approve answers to questions when you have an answer that works for you.  This is your second question and you haven't accepted the answer for your first question yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total time should be calculated as

```
totalTime = end - start
```

All durations are in minutes, so the following is already in minutes, and does not need to be multiplied by 60:

```
timeWorked = (totalTime - lunchTime)
```

Now you have `timeWorked` in minutes, so in hours that is:

```
hoursWorked = int(timeWorked / 60)
```

and the minutes would be the remainder:

```
minutesWorked = timeWorked % 60
```

The last 2 statements could be replaced with `divmod()`:

```
hoursWorked, minutesWorked = divmod(timeWorked, 60)
```

Comment: so what does divmod do exactly?

Comment: @CharlesTaylor : you can check the documentation for [divmod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod). Basically it produces the quotient and remainder of a division operation. In this case the divisor is 60 because that's how many minutes there are in 1 hour